# Impossible to remove rows from matrix with Math.NET Numerics

Tags: c#, matrix, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have a weird problem with Math.NET Numerics. Let say I have a `matrix<double>` well instantiated and filled (I verified by writing it in a text file), which size is (949 x 30).
All I want is to remove a row from this matrix. But it seems that I can't remove all the rows I want. I can remove all the columns I want, but I just can remove the 30 first rows (maybe this is related to the number of columns which is 30). See my code :

```
Matrix<double> mat = getMatrixFromDico();
MessageBox.Show(mat.RowCount + " x " + mat.ColumnCount); // output is 949 x 30
mat = mat.RemoveColumn(25); // works perfectly
mat = mat.RemoveRow(25); // works perfectly
mat = mat.RemoveRow(35); // throws a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Does someone have an idea what's going on ?

I think I have tested and verified everything about  `mat`. It's really a (949 x 30) matrix and well filled with double values.

**Edit**

I think this is the library's problem. The function might be not well implemented and works only with square matrix OR with the row/columns of the square sub-matrix of a non-square matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a bug in the argument range check in v3.0.1.
A fixed version 3.0.2 will be released shortly.

Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: Update: v3.0.2 now available on NuGet